# Add custom dropdown in mini Search magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, custom, catalogsearch

**How to add this functionality** 
any one can help me

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit **"app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme_Name/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml"** file and add your select field after the input field like below -

```
<div class="control">
    <input id="search"
       data-mage-init='{"quickSearch":{
            "formSelector":"#search_mini_form",
            "url":"<?= $block->escapeUrl($helper->getSuggestUrl())?>",
            "destinationSelector":"#search_autocomplete"}
       }'
       type="text"
       name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($helper->getQueryParamName()) ?>"
       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($helper->getEscapedQueryText()) ?>"
       placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Search here...')) ?>"
       class="input-text"
       maxlength="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($helper->getMaxQueryLength()) ?>"
       role="combobox"
       aria-haspopup="false"
       aria-autocomplete="both"
       autocomplete="off"
       aria-expanded="false"/>
    <select class="search-type" id="searchType" name="type">
        <option value="es" <?php if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='es') echo "selected";?>>Entire Site</option>
        <option value="sv" <?php if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='sv') echo "selected";?>>Selected Vehicle</option>
        <option value="pn" <?php if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='pn') echo "selected";?>>Part number</option>
    </select>
    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</div>
```

After that overwrite **Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Search\Plugin\CollectionFilter** file and add like filter to the collection like below-

```
$query = $this->queryFactory->get();
if (!$query->isQueryTextShort()) {
    $collection->addSearchFilter($query->getQueryText());
}
$type = $this->request->getParam('type');
if ($type=='sv') {
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
        'sku',
        array(
            array('like' => '% '.$query->getQueryText().' %'), //spaces on each side
            array('like' => '% '.$query->getQueryText()), //space before and ends with $needle
            array('like' => $query->getQueryText().' %') // starts with needle and space after
        )
    );
}
```

**It may not be a great solution but it will do the work.**